# How do I open and run this Java project in Eclipse for OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, cryptography

I'm trying to open and run (Step through) the Java app [Idemix from IBM.](https://prime.inf.tu-dresden.de/idemix/)

I'm new to java and [attempted to import the file, as described here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419556/vc/Open-existing-project-Eclipse), however when I browse to the directory, and even when I search subdirectories, then I'm unable to see any project suitable for import.

I feel a bit lost, being new to this and all.  My main goal is to figure out how large, in bytes a token is for Idemix for a non-interactive zero knowledge proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the project and classpath files have been renamed in the download. The files in the download are called `_project` and `_classpath` and need to be renamed to `.project` and `.classpath`.

Note: On the Mac files starting with `.` are hidden and will not be shown in Finder. You can see them in Terminal using the `ls -a` command.